# Spring Integration - Multicast UDP message not updating

Tags: spring-boot, udp, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I try to listen periodic udp message with Multicast ip with spring integration, but my code get the same udp message all the time even if the udp message updated. When I stop my program and restart it, the message updates.
Here is my config config.java:

```
 @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow udpIn() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Udp.inboundMulticastAdapter(16343, "239.0.12.1"))
                .channel("inboundChannel")
                .get();
    }
```

and here is the method handle messages service.java:

```
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "inboundChannel")
    public void handleMessage(Message message) {
        log.info("message.getPayload());
        byte[] values = (byte[]) message.getPayload();
        //some irrelevant code
}
```

where is wrong about the code?

Thanks...